# Protect routes dynamically, based on id (laravel, pivot table)

Tags: php, laravel, routes, pivot, authorization

This topic has been discussed a lot here, but I don't get it.

I would like to protect my routes with pivot tables (user_customer_relation, user_object_relation (...)) but I don't understand, how to apply the filter correctly.

```
Route::get('customer/{id}', 'CustomerController@getCustomer')->before('customer')
```

now I can add some values to the before filter

```
->before('customer:2')
```

How can I do this dynamically?

In the filter, I can do something like:

```
if(!User::hasAccessToCustomer($id)) {
    App::abort(403); 
}
```

In the hasAccessToCustomer function:

```
public function hasCustomer($id) {
    if(in_array($id, $this->customers->lists('id'))) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

How do I pass the customer id to the filter correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass a route parameter to a filter. However you can access route parameters from pretty much everywhere in the app using `Route::input()`:

```
$id = Route::input('id');
```

#### Optimizations

```
public function hasCustomer($id) {
    if($this->customers()->find($id)){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Or actually even

```
public function hasCustomer($id) {
    return !! $this->customers()->find($id)
}
```

(The double `!!` will cast the `null` / `Customer` result as a boolean)

#### Generic approach

Here's a possible, more generic approach to the problem: (It's not tested though)

```
Route::filter('id_in_related', function($route, $request, $relationName){
    $user = Auth::user();
    if(!$user->{$relationName}()->find($route->parameter('id')){
        App::abort(403);
    }
});
```

And here's how you would use it:

```
->before('id_in_related:customers')
->before('id_in_related:objects')
// and so on
```

Comment: Thanks! Is my approach suitable? Or would you recommend a better solution?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Although you could for sure optimize `hasCustomer` a bit. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Maybe this task is easy but at the beginning it has been very confusing to me. Further, I'm thinking of a more general way to check the permission because if I would have later > 10 pages to protect, I'm creating nearly ten times the same filter?

Comment: And all the filters would work the same? (If the id is in the related models of user grant access)

Comment: Yes, currently this is my approach. Maybe I will extend it later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68911/discussion-between-wiesson-and-lukasgeiter).